# Is it possible to use parameter pack instead of sequence of nested templates?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Hy, I am crafting some meta-programming library that could help to construct complex objects from simple ad-mixture classes through the inheritance.

For instance I got some mechanisms those produce a set of template classes, each representing a single property.

I`ve came to a final construction procedure that looks like this:

```
class Car : public Position< Size< Color< BaseObj<Car> > > > {/*...*/};
```

and i quite don't like it.
(BaseObj is always the most inner template in a sequence)

I tried to make some processing template to be able to write it like this:

```
class Car : public Proc< Position, Size, Color, Car > {/*...*/};
```

but got no success.

Is it possible to make such a template?
Are there any other more readable semantics those could have the same effect as a sequence of such nested templates?

Comment: I think maybe it can be done. But what you want to achieve is unclear to me (a `Size` as parameter to `Position` is really strange).

Comment: First of all I need a set of classes those could be inherited one from another in a row with in a most simple way. Templates are just the way to inherit 'in depth' not 'in width'. Consider each template as a mixture-component (order does not matter).

Answer (score 5):

So, you want...

```
nest<A, B, C, D>::type<E>
```

...to become...

```
A<B<C<D<E>>>>
```

This is a job for recursion.

---

```
template <template <typename> typename...>
struct nest;

template <template <typename> typename First, 
          template <typename> typename... Rest>
struct nest<First, Rest...>
{
    template <typename Leaf>
    using type = First<typename nest<Rest...>::template type<Leaf>>;
};

template <template <typename> typename Last>
struct nest<Last>
{
    template <typename Leaf>
    using type = Last<Leaf>;
};
```

Usage example:

```
template <typename> struct A { };
template <typename> struct B { };
template <typename> struct C { };
template <typename> struct D { };
struct E { };

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<
        typename nest<A, B, C, D>::template type<E>,
        A<B<C<D<E>>>>
    >);
}
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Spv4peRfJnjr2MxU)

Comment: You don't really need the `typename` and `template` keywords in the `static_assert` they are not dependent names.

Comment: @SirGuy You kinda forget once you deal with enough templates ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I`ve been pretty close to your construction yet could not make it work.

Comment: @Gleb In the future, could you please include what you have tried as well, in order to make clear what kind of solution you are looking for?

Comment: @oisyn yes, I`ll try to do that anywhere it is possible

Comment: @Vittorio, just in case... I`ve found some sort of bug in MSVC - your code does not compile 'as is'. The problem seems to be in struct forward declaration. However removing it at all and leaving recursive definition as the most general declaration works fine. This fix seems to work on g++ and clang as well. Thanks again for the answer itself.

Answer (score -2):

**Edit** It appears that I misunderstood the question. I thought you wanted to change your design to simply use a list of traits, rather than having traits nested recursively. I now understand you're simply looking for a drop-in replacement that allows you to write a list, that boils down to your old design. But that leaves the question: why do you really want to stick with that design? What purpose does it serve? I'm assuming the only reason it was like that, was that you weren't able to use variadic templates before.

I think my answer is still viable, but it requires changing your current implementation of Position, Size, Color, etc. I can't really suggest how until you provide a more clear description of what those things do.

Old answer:

Well, it would be a bit easier if you put the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)-argument in front.

```
template<class S, class... P>
class Proc : public P...
{
    // ...
};

class Car : public Proc<Car, Position, Size, Color> {/*...*/};
```

Comment: That would work if `Car`, `Position', etc were types, but they are templates so this will not work.

Comment: They are only templates because he uses template recursion, which he wanted to implement differently. He hasn't really defined what those things *are*.

Comment: Correction, which *I thought* he wanted to implement differently.

Comment: Those classes are templates in order to be able to inherit from them in various combinations. For example Car has Size, Position and color while Bus also has Capacity and Bike has only position. These templates simply inherit their single argument.This technique allows to avoid a lot of code duplication and at the same time avoid 'tree' multiple inheritance.